# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getValue'

Tags: extjs, extjs4, typeerror

I am currently attempting to add a listener to my button so that when it is clicked it loads what is in the 'textId' textfield into an html text above said textfield and button. This is so they can enter multiple things into this field and delete them if one is not needed afterwards because the text gets loaded in with a delete button.

```
createTextAndButton: function(fieldId, v, textId, field, text, num) {
    var n = new Number(num);
    var ct = new Ext.container.Container({
        xtype:"container",
        layout:"vbox",
        //padding:"5 0",
        items: [{
            xtype:"container",
            itemId: fieldId,
            }, {
            xtype: "container",
            layout:"hbox",
            padding: "5 0",
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                vtype: v,
                name: textId,
                fieldLabel: field,
                validateOnBlur: true
            }, {
                xtype: "button",
                text: text,
                width: 115,
                handler: function() {
                    ct.down('#' + fieldId).add(Ext.ComponentMgr.create({
                        xtype: "container",
                        itemId: 'entry' + n,
                        layout: "hbox",
                        padding: "5 0",
                        items: [{
                            xtype: "component",
                            html: "<p>" + textId.getValue() + "</p>"
                        }, {
                            xtype: "button",
                            itemId: 'dButton',
                            text: "delete",
                            width: 80
                            }
                        }]
                    }));
                    n++;
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
    return ct;
}
```

I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Object ignoreField has no method 'getValue' when I click on the button. I'm unsure why the textfields getValue method is not working or if I am doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: If you are passing the id of the textfield which is `textId` you may want to try

 `html:  Ext.Container.getComponent ('textId').getValue()`

Comment: getComponent isn't a static method.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Oh I see. I also noticed I have an error in my comment. What I meant to put was `Ext.container.Container.getComponent`. I was also going off the docs and read that its best to use the approach above with itemIds which lead to my suggestion. But you are correct, even then it's not the correct way to use it.http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-itemId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all those who attempted helping me solve this question. I was able to figure out where my fault was. for my textfields I should be using just the `id:` tag not `name:` or `itemId` Here is the working code for those who care.

```
createTextAndButton: function(fieldId,  textId, field, text, num) {
    var n = new Number(num);
    var ct = new Ext.container.Container({
        xtype:"container",
        layout:"vbox",
        //padding:"5 0",
        items: [{
            xtype:"container",
            itemId: fieldId,
            }, {
            xtype: "container",
            layout:"hbox",
            padding: "5 0",
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                id: textId,
                fieldLabel: field,
                validateOnBlur: true
            }, {
                xtype: "button",
                text: text,
                width: 115,
                handler: function() {
                    ct.down('#' + fieldId).add(Ext.ComponentMgr.create({
                        xtype: "container",
                        Id: 'entry' + n,
                        layout: "hbox",
                        padding: "5 0",
                        items: [{
                            xtype: "component",
                            html: "<p>" + Ext.getCmp(textId).getValue() + "</p>"
                        }, {
                            xtype: "button",
                            itemId: 'dButton',
                            text: "delete",
                            width: 80
                        }]
                    }));
                    n++;
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
    return ct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

itemId is local to a particular container, getCmp() will only retrieve the global id for a component.

It would be much easier to do something like:

```
createTextAndButton: function(fieldId, type, v, textId, field, text) {
    var ct = new Ext.container.Container({
        xtype:"container",
        layout:"vbox",
        //padding:"5,0",
        items: [{
            xtype:"container",
            itemId: fieldId,
            },{
            xtype: "container",
            layout:"hbox",
            padding: "5 0",
            items: [{
                xtype: type,
                vtype: v,
                itemId: textId,
                fieldLabel: field,
                validateOnBlur: true
            }, {
                xtype: "button",
                text: text,
                width: 115,
                handler: function() {
                    ct.down('#' + fieldId).add(new Ext.container.Container({
                        xtype: "container",
                        padding: "5 0",
                        items: [{
                            xtype: "component",
                            autoEl: "pre",
                            html: textId.getValue()
                        }, {
                            xtype: "button",
                            text: "delete",
                            width: 115
                        }]
                    }));
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
    return ct;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the semicolon in this line: `ct.down('#' + fieldId);.add(new Ext.container.Conatiner({` When it exists the code does not run due to an unchecked error on that line, I'm assuming it is that. Also I still receive the same error after changing my code to incorporate your proposed fix.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions your current proposed fix results in the same error after I incorporate it into my code?